# How to target Windows XP sp3 when compiling with Visual C++ 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, windows-xp, target

I am trying to compile a C++ program using Visual Studio 2010 Pro on a Windows 7 computer to target Windows XP sp3 32 bits.

I've played around with the compiler and linker settings, but I'm unable to produce an executable that can run on my Windows XP computer. I always get the error "Could not find entry point for function GetTickCount64 in kernel32.dll" and the program doesn't run. I know Windows XP does not support GetTickCount64() and I'm not using it in my code anyways.

I don't have other versions of Visual Studio installed, and I already installed Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package on the windows XP machine.

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Thanks before hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VC2010 targets Windows 7 by default.
To change target to XP, check [Using the Windows Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I followed that article and I was able to make the program work.